# JS/jQuery - stop .on('click') from sending twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a **JS** global event handler which looks like this (this is temp code):

```js
$(document).on('click', '.my-class, #box-in-my-class', function(e) {
  console.log($(this), 'was clicked!');
  if ($(this).is('my-class')) {
    $(this).children('.dropdown').toggleClass('active');
  }

  if ($(this).is('#box-in-my-class')) {
    $('#expander').toggleClass('active');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="my-class">
  <div class="other-bit"></div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <div id="box-in-my-class"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="expander"></div>
```

(the `.active` class added makes the div bigger - through css).

However, in running this, when I click the `#box-in-my-class`, I get this in the `console`:

`#box-in-my-class was clicked!`

`.my-class was clicked!`

which toggles the dropdown (closing it).

**How do I set it so that when you click the child of an element it does not bubble/propagate/etc. so that I can click the `#box-in-my-class` w/o running `.my-class`**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your event bubbles. In the code you must call `e.stopPropagation()`; And also you have some missed `')'`.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.my-class, #box-in-my-class', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log(e.target, 'was clicked!');
  if ($(this).is('my-class')) {
    $(this).children('.dropdown').toggleClass('active');
  }

  if ($(this).is('#box-in-my-class')) {
    $('#expander').toggleClass('active');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="my-class">
  <div class="other-bit"></div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <div id="box-in-my-class">Test 1</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="expander">Test 2</div>
```

For more see [event bubbling](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html)

and [e.stopPropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
$(document).on('click', '.my-class, #box-in-my-class', function(e) {

  if ($(this).is('.my-class') && $(e.target).is(':not(#box-in-my-class')) {//check if the clicked element is not box-in-my-class
    console.log($(this), 'was clicked!');
    $(this).children('.dropdown').toggleClass('active');
  }

  if ($(this).is('#box-in-my-class')) {
    $('#expander').toggleClass('active');
  }
}
```

demo:http://jsfiddle.net/0yvuzm0c/

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't use 2 if class when you only need one response.

If I were you, I would write my JS function like this:

```
if ($(this).is('#box-in-my-class') {
    $('#expander').toggleClass('active');
    return;
}else if ($(this).is('my-class') {
    $(this).children('.dropdown').toggleClass('active');
    return;
}
```

I will check this $('#box-in-my-class') first due to the reason that  $('#box-in-my-class') is the child of $(.'my-class').
In this case, if it detected $('#box-in-my-class') is clicked, it will stop the loop. instead of checking $(.'my-class') too.

You may study http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp to be more familiar with if, else, else if loop.